# Me aparece el mismo error en phpUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Siempre que voy a ejecutar el test unitario de php en symfony me aparece este error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException:
>   Environment variable not found: "APP_SECRET".

Answer (score 0):

No dices que versión de symfony usas, pero seguramente el error viene porque falta definir alguna variable sea en el parameters.yml o como en el caso de tu error, en el .env .

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html